# Upgrading from Magento 2.2 to 2.3 Undefined index

Tags: magento2.3, database, magento2.2, upgrade

I created a new installation of a Magento 2.3.5-p2 and I want to use or get the data from a database that were used in a Magento 2.2 installation.
I corrected the type from some tables that could not be enum that's fine but then this appears when I run setup:upgrade

```
Notice: Undefined index: CUST_pecustomer_entity in /var/www/webroot/ROOT/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 152
```

And idk what to do, it doesn't seem to be an old extension problem that's a core table that's why I'm kinda lost here.
I checked in app/etc/config.php and the search is already at 'Magento_Search' => 1 and searched database for any references to CUST_pecustomer_entity but no luck.
Any solution for this?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that helped, in vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php:148 change to this

```
//Prepare reference data
                $referenceData['table'] = $table;
                $referenceTableName = $referenceData['referenceTable'];
                $referenceData['column'] = $table->getColumnByName($referenceData['column']);
                if(!isset($this->tables[$referenceTableName])){
                    var_dump($tableName);exit;
                }
                $referenceData['referenceTable'] = $this->tables[$referenceTableName];
                $referenceData['referenceColumn'] = $referenceData['referenceTable']->getColumnByName(
                    $referenceData['referenceColumn']
                );
```

it will return the table that is giving errors. You should override this file so you can edit, in my case I just wanted to use one time so edited directly in vendor and then reverted it, if you want to keep it override the file. I don't advise doing this on a production server. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: May I ask why downvote? Only wanted to help someone with a similar problem since the warning that Magento gives by default is not that great, I could never find where it was with just the default warning. But if someone wants to add something or have a better way I would appreciate it, this one was what I found so I could solve the problem and I lost a couple of hours just to get that little debug so I could solve the problem so I didn't want someone to lose that many time with this :D